# Install wine on fedora 34

Tags: fedora, wine

I'm new to fedora and I have installed fedora 34 a few days ago.
But I can't find out how can I install wine on fedora 34. Because any website I check, the latest release of wine is for fedora 33:

https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/fedora/33/winehq.repo

Can anybody help please?

Answer (score 4):

Wine is available from the Fedora repositories; currently Fedora 34 has Wine 6.7:

```
sudo dnf install wine
```

On `x86_64` this will also pull in `i686` dependencies so that 32- and 64-bit Windows programs can run.

Answer (score 1):

As with previous fedora versions, you can install.

```
sudo dnf install wine
```

Changing the version of your distribution does not necessarily mean changing the way programs are installed

Answer (score 0):

Here's one very important peculiarity about Linux distros:

**Whenever possible you must never install 3d-party software in them**. This also means that **whenever possible you should never use third-party repos** (you may have seen Fedora's copr repos - they are **also** 3d-party software).

Most modern Linux distros contain some sort of Software Center, so, please use it to install software.

The reason behind all of that is because Linux distros are not concerned with backwards compatibility so major upgrades, e.g. Fedora 33 to 34 may either break your 3d party apps, or this upgrade may become impossible due to the existence of 3d-party applications.

If you gain enough experience you'll be able to easily navigate 3d-party repositories and software but until that please stick to what your distro offers out of the box.